# Puede crystal report generar este formato?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Quiero generar este formato en crystal report en visual studio. Ya que necesito varias secciones , de repeticion, seccion de texto con campos tomados de la base, luego mas repeticion y el diseñador de crystal ya tiene definidas sus secciones.
Es posible generar este tipo de formato?

[image: Formato carta]

Answer (score 1):

En crystal puedes agregar secciones solo que estas estan pensadas para generar cortes de control sobre los datos para agruparlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La secccion de Details es una sola, pero podrias crear subreportes si necesitas tener un detalle diferente sobre un grupo de datos.

[Step by Step Creation of Crystal Report using its Features Group, Graph, Cross-Tab and Sub Report](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its)

Analiza el título "5. Sub Report in Crystal Report"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]